# An error occurred, in the Laravel project I am doing php artisan migrate, a number of these errors are taking off

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, php7, error404

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant 'PREG_UNMATCHED_AS_NULL' in /sites/fkrkm.ua.insave.ovh/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/Helper.php:52
Stack trace:
#0 /sites/fkrkm.ua.insave.ovh/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(826): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Helper::strlen('Use of undefine...')
#1 /sites/fkrkm.ua.insave.ovh/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(795): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRenderThrowable(Object(ErrorException), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#2 /sites/fkrkm.ua.insave.ovh/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(665): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->renderThrowable(Object(ErrorException), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /sites/fkrkm.ua.insave.ovh/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(108): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->renderForConsole(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput), Object(ErrorException))
#4 /sites/fkrkm.ua in /sites/fkrkm.ua.insave.ovh/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/Helper.php on line 52
```

Как решить данную проблему? Когда делал php artisan migrate

[image: Когда делал на хосте]

После сделал composer update появились ошибки которые выше..

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса // и заголовок переведите, пожалуйста, на русский язык (нажав [edit])

Comment: Константа эта появилась в версии 7.2, установите себе более свежий интерпритатор как вам и говорит композер, 7.3 и старше